# DataGrid is updating itself in realtime and holding unsaved changes

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I have a problem with DataGrid and after week trying to solve this I am out of mind.

I am using Prism.MVVM to handle loading properties, INotifyPropertyChanged etc.

My datagrid is being populated from database (EF) by of course ViewModel. When I double click on the row edit window will open with populated fields etc. I am doing this by "SelectedItem". Everything to this moment is working fine, but:

• When I editing my "Stock" textbox I see in the ProductListView window that this value is changing in realtime and even if I hit Cancel (and the window closed) it stays as I left it in ProductView and even after opening edit window again "Stock" value remain wrong, but in database the value is correct.

• When I edit for example "Category" or "Name" I do not see changes in datagrid in realtime (in this case values in DataGrid stay correct), but if I hit Cancel (and the window closed) an reopen edit window again value remain wrong, but in database the value is correct.

I tried to DeepCopy it and then Override SelectedItem back after edit and it work for database (it getting updated), but view (DataGrid) does not.

**ProductListView:**

```
    <DataGrid ColumnWidth="Auto" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding ProductsCollectionView, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True"
ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
```

**Methods/Commands responsible for edit in ProductListViewModel:**

```
    private Product _selectedItem;
    public Product SelectedItem
    {
        get => _selectedItem;
        set => SetProperty(ref _selectedItem, value);
    }

public ProductListViewModel() // Contructor
    {
        _service = new ProductService();

        Load();
        ProductsCollectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Data);
        ProductsCollectionView.Filter = FilterProducts;
        LoadCommands();

        EditCommand = new DelegateCommand(Edit);

    }


public ICommand EditCommand { get; set; }

private void Edit()
    {    
        var dialog = new ProductView(SelectedItem);
        dialog.ShowDialog();

        if (dialog.DialogResult == true)
        {
            _service.UpdateProductData(SelectedItem);
            _service.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

**ProductView** (Btw. I am using same View for Adding and Editing products, that is why I passing "SeleectedItem through the constructor)

```
<StackPanel Margin="0,0,13,0" Grid.Column="0">
                <TextBlock Text="Product type" Style="{StaticResource StackPanelTextBox}"/>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="41*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="251*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="31*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ComboBox IsEditable="True" IsTextSearchEnabled="True" ItemsSource="{Binding ProductTypes}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="ProductTypeId" SelectedValue="{Binding Data.ProductTypeId, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
                    <Button Grid.Column="1" Command="{Binding AddProductTypeCommand}" FontSize="12" Padding="0" Height="15" Background="Transparent" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="251,6,0,6"/>
                </Grid>
            </StackPanel>

            <StackPanel Margin="0,0,13,0" Grid.Column="1">
                <TextBlock Text="Signature" Style="{StaticResource StackPanelTextBox}"/>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Data.Signature}"/>
            </StackPanel>

            <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,0" Grid.Column="2">
                <TextBlock Text="EAN" Style="{StaticResource StackPanelTextBox}"/>
                <TextBox MaxLength="13" Text="{Binding Data.Ean}"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="80*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,7,13,10">
                    <TextBlock Text="Name" Style="{StaticResource StackPanelTextBox}"/>
                    <TextBox x:Name="tbName" Text="{Binding Data.Name}"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <TextBlock Text="Stock"/>
                    <mah:NumericUpDown Margin="0,3,0,3" Minimum="0" Interval="1" Value="{Binding Data.InStock}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
```

**ProductView.xaml.cs**

```
public ProductView(Product product)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var viewModel = new ProductViewModel(product);
            WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;

            viewModel.SaveAction = () =>
            {
                DialogResult = true;
            };

            viewModel.CancelAction = () =>
            {
                DialogResult = false;
            };

            DataContext = viewModel;
        }
```

**ProductViewModel**

```
public Action SaveAction { get; set; }
        public Action CancelAction { get; set; }
        public ICommand Save { get; set; }
        public ICommand Cancel { get; set; }


        private Product _data;
        public Product Data
        {
            get => _data;
            set => SetProperty(ref _data, value);
        }

        public ProductViewModel(Product data)
        {
            LoadSellers();
            LoadProductTypes();
            LoadPackages();

            Data = data;
            NettoPrice = Data.PurchasePrice;

            Save = new DelegateCommand(() => SaveAction?.Invoke());
            Cancel = new DelegateCommand(() => CancelAction?.Invoke());
            HideData = new DelegateCommand(HideMethod);
            AddProductTypeCommand = new DelegateCommand(AddProductType);
            EyeColor = @"..\Resources\Images\Eye-grey-48.png";
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an extra data layer if you want to implement edit and cancel behavior of a data model. You can do this by implementing the [IEditableObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.ieditableobject?view=net-6.0) interface.

You should never open the dialog from the view model. Instead, open it from a `Button.Click` handler in the code-behind. Define a `DataTemplate` for the dialog and assign it to the `Window.ContentTemplate` property. Also make sure that the database handling is implemented inside the model.

The following example shows how to display a reusable `EditDialog` (that operates on `IEditableObject` implementations) from the view. The example also shows how to cancel or commit data changes to the data model.

**App.xaml**

```xml
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Product}">
  <TextBox Text="{Binding Signature}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

**EditDialog.xaml**
Reusable dialog. Simply define a `DataTemplate` for the `Window.ContentTemplate` property to change the hosted `Content`.
Assign the data to be edited to the `EditDialog.DataContext`. This dialog can host any data that implements `IEditableObject`.

```xml
<Window Content="{Binding}">
  <Window.Template>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Window">
      <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition />
          <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <AdornerDecorator Grid.Row="0">
          <ContentPresenter />
        </AdornerDecorator>

        <!-- Dialog chrome -->
        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
          <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button Content="Commit"
                    Click="OnOkButtonClicked" />
            <Button Content="Cancel"
                    Click="OnCancelButtonClicked"
                    IsCancel="True"
                    IsDefault="True" />
          </StackPanel>

          <ResizeGrip x:Name="WindowResizeGrip"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                      VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                      Visibility="Collapsed"
                      IsTabStop="false" />
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
      <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="ResizeMode"
                 Value="CanResizeWithGrip">
          <Setter TargetName="WindowResizeGrip"
                  Property="Visibility"
                  Value="Visible" />
        </Trigger>
      </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
  </Window.Template>
</Window>
```

**EditDialog.xaml.cs**

```cs
public partial class EditDialog : Window
{
  public EditDialog()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Loaded += OnLoaded;
  }

  // In case the Window is closed using the chrome button
  protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e)
  {
    if (this.Content is IEditableObject editableObject)
    {
      editableObject.CancelEdit();
    }
    base.OnClosing(e);
  }

  private void OnLoaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    // Content is set via data binding
    if (this.Content is IEditableObject editableObject)
    {
      editableObject.BeginEdit();
    }
  }

  private void OnCancelButtonClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    if (this.Content is IEditableObject editableObject)
    {
      editableObject.CancelEdit();
    }
    this.Close();
  }

  private void OnOkButtonClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    if (this.Content is IEditableObject editableObject)
    {
      editableObject.EndEdit();
    }
    this.Close();
  }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ProductsCollectionView}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}">
  <DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
      <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick"
                   Handler="DataGridRow_MouseDoubleClick" />
    </Style>
  </DataGrid.RowStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = new ProductListViewModel();
  }

  private void DataGridRow_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
  {
    var productListViewModel = this.DataContext as ProductListViewModel;

    // Alternatively, create a e.g., EditItem dependency property
    // and bind it to the DataGrid.SelectedItem
    Product editItem = productListViewModel.SelectedItem;

    var editDialog = new EditDialog()
    {
      DataContext = editItem 
    };
    editDialog.ShowDialog();
  }
}
```

**Product.cs**

```cs
class Product : INotifyPropertyChanged, IEditableObject
{
  internal class ProductData
  {
    // Use object.MemberwiseClone to create a shallow copy
    public ProductData Clone() => MemberwiseClone() as ProductData;

    public string Signature { get; set; }
  }

  public Product()
  {
    this.EditData = new ProductData();
    this.BackupData = new ProductData();
  }

  public void BeginEdit()
  {
    if (this.IsInEditMode)
    {
      // Consider to throw an exception
      return;
    }

    // Creates a shallow copy.
    // If required, use a copy constructor to create a deep copy.
    this.BackupData = this.EditData.Clone();

    this.IsInEditMode = true;
  }

  public void CancelEdit()
  {
    if (!this.IsInEditMode)
    {
      // Consider to throw an exception
      return;
    }
    this.EditData = this.BackupData;
    this.IsInEditMode = false;

    // Raise change notification for all public properties
    // to undo potential binding changes
    OnPropertyChanged(null);
  }

  public void EndEdit()
  {
    this.IsInEditMode = false;
  }

  public string Signature
  {
    get => this.EditData.Signature;
    set
    {
      this.EditData.Signature = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  public bool IsInEditMode { get; private set; }
  private ProductData BackupData { get; set; }
  private ProductData EditData { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for late answer and accepting a solution, but I spend last month learning and understanding what you said and finally I did, so thank you so much for such a comprehensive answer! ;)